# How can we validate file type in model using carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, carrierwave

I have model document looks like

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader
  belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

How can I use multiple uploader dependent on a field lets say document_type
so that I can do some thing like this

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader, if: document_type == "Image"
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader, if: document_type == "Agreement"
  belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

or there is any way by which I can use extension_white_list on model level. Basically I want to attach pdf file if document type is agreement and if document type is image only image files should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `extension_white_list` in your model, something like this:

```
  class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    def extension_white_list
      if document_type == 'agreement'
        %w(pdf doc docx xls xlsx)
      elsif document_type == 'image'
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
      else
        # do something else
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: i am getting nil in document_type